# How to print driverless to a brother HL-L2350DW on windows 11

Tags: networking, windows-11, printing, brother-printer

I am able to print from my pixel 7 easily out of the box to my two brother printers HL-L2350DW and MFC-L2740DW. I believe it uses IPP protocol but for some reason can not take advantage of this via windows 11. I would like to not have to enter the printer's IP address as my local home network uses DHCP so I'd like my printing solution to be robust and work regardless of the IP address assigned.

Is there a driverless print method in Windows? If so, how do I use it for this printer.

Comment: Are the printers installed and usable on the Windows computer?

Comment: I haven't tried that. Have been hopeful for the driver-less printing that is working on the pixel. I will try that this evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the HL-L2350DW I just needed to turn on wireless on my PC workstation which was hardwired and the IPP drivers are working on my windows PC. Did not need to install a driver on my laptop (windows 11) and surface (windows 10) and when I do a test page it will say it is using the "Microsoft IPP Class Driver" for systems where the Brother Drivers were not installed. Unfortunately just having a wired connection to the network is not good enough, needs to be wireless on the PC itself for this printer to work. Odd but I can live with this and happy to see "driverless" printing work on windows.

Note: wireless driverless printing does not appear to work smoothly on my older MFC-L2740DW.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/what-s-new-in-windows-11-for-universal-print/ba-p/2499026

Comment: Windows has a big catalog of printer drivers and I think you will find Windows supplied the driver.

Comment: I also added to my post the concept of Universal Print ready printers and Windows 11 Universal Print Driver.  None of this is "driverless" printing as you asked.

Comment: @John Did two more test printing the test page which tells me if it is using the installed driver or the IPP driver. I specifically did not install any drivers manually on my laptop and surface and for the driver it says: "Microsoft IPP Class Driver" Driver Type = "Type 4 - User Mode" For the system where I did install the driver it says: "Brother HL-L2350DW series" Driver Type = "Type 3 - User Mode"

Answer (score 2):

I think the other device is using Air Print (not really driverless) and so far as I know Windows does not have Air Print.

I installed the proper drivers on my Windows (10 and 11) computers and print works. I have Air Print on my iPhone and print works.  No need to worry about IP address - the correct drivers do that.

You can also (for the majority of printers) just use the Windows built in print driver facility. Just use Settings, Printers, Add a Printer. This works fine for most print jobs.

With Windows 11 and its new Universal Print Driver, it can print to the cloud, and also on Universal Print ready printers.  This may work, but it is not true driverless printing. That does not exist so far as I know.

Comment: ty, driverless would be ideal but this is still viable solution, I will test this this evening

Comment: I am quite certain there is no Air Print ("driverless as you think") on a Windows computer.

Comment: air print appears to be proprietary by apple and not supported by android pixels but IPP is a standard printing protocol allowing driver-less printing which I feel would be beneficial to many if Microsoft could add support for it. Also looks like Airprint is based on IPP:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_printing_protocols#Wireless_protocols

Comment: I have not seen any driverless print protocol on Windows

Comment: in the link above it does say windows 10 supports Morpheus alliance approach (what is used by android) but maybe it is not mature and has been removed or because I am using windows 11.

Comment: @simgineer - Windows 11 does support IPP printer drivers.  However, the driver has to exist, and if it does not then you have no choice but to use a legacy driver.  [While there is a plan to sunset third-party drivers, it's several years away, from being implemented.](https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-announces-the-end-of-servicing-for-third-party-printer-drivers-on-windows/).  Even when fully implemented, using a legacy printer driver, will be likely remain possible for at least another decade from an end user point of view.  Driverless solution does not exist

Comment: Also it is no big deal to add a printer to Windows (7, 8, 10 and 11) in Add a Printer.

Comment: @Ramhound when you say IPP driver needs to exist does that mean brother needs to write an IPP driver for windows like it has for android and AirPrint and it is transferred at print time or a generic one time IPP driver will work for all IPP enabled printers and this generic driver needs to be written for windows and this has yet to occur? Just to clarify for my understanding driverless solutions exist for mobile phone OSs but just not yet windows, is this correct?

Comment: @simgineer - Yes; Somebody needs to develop the IPP driver for the printer.

Comment: I installed the drivers and turned on the wireless network on my PC and things started working. Unfortunately if I had turned on the wireless connection first wo installing the driver I'd know if it was IPP working out of the box. There have been suggestions that IPP on a PC requires wireless to be active. Honestly there is quite a bit I don't know about wireless printing but happy to be able to print now.

Comment: Why do you suggest Air Print "not really driverless"?
https://openprinting.github.io/driverless/01-standards-and-their-pdls/

Comment: The air print driver on my iPhone regularly installs driver updates.

Comment: I suppose we can look at it that way, basically a generic driver which if a printer manufacturer makes all their printers compliant to they no longer need to create a dedicated driver for each platform per model. But it still achieves not having to update a driver when introducing new printer hw to the network which is awesome IMO. My guess is those updates to the airprint driver are just improving or patching existing airprint driver families.